# Why is my pip-installed Python script not executable for everyone?

Tags: permissions, python, pip

In [my Vagrant instance](https://github.com/l0b0/root/blob/9975d09c43ad4eb2969d70781fb6a33582bbe68e/Vagrantfile):

```
vagrant@archlinux:~$ sudo pip2 install vcard
Downloading/unpacking vcard
  Downloading vcard-0.9.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/vcard/setup.py) egg_info for package vcard

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): isodate in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from vcard)
Installing collected packages: vcard
  Running setup.py install for vcard

    Installing vcard script to /usr/bin
Successfully installed vcard
Cleaning up...
vagrant@archlinux:~$ ls -l $(which vcard)
which: no vcard in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl)
total 0
vagrant@archlinux:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/vcard
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root 286 Nov  9 10:42 /usr/bin/vcard
```

**`/usr/bin/vcard` is only executable by root. What gives?**

On my up-to-date [Arch Linux machine](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/tree/b31218a91418884b0ddfa85998d76258fe228c1f) it works as expected:

```
$ sudo pip2 install vcard
Downloading/unpacking vcard
  Downloading vcard-0.9.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/vcard/setup.py) egg_info for package vcard

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): isodate in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from vcard)
Installing collected packages: vcard
  Running setup.py install for vcard

    Installing vcard script to /usr/bin
Successfully installed vcard
Cleaning up...
$ ls -l $(which vcard)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 286 Nov  9 10:40 /usr/bin/vcard
```

`/usr/bin/vcard` is executable by everyone.

---

It seems this is caused by a restrictive umask:

```
vagrant@archlinux:~$ sudo bash -c umask
0027
```

Turns out it's set in the both the vagrant and root users's `.profile`, for [unknown reasons](https://github.com/terrywang/vagrantboxes/issues/16):

```
vagrant@archlinux:~$ sudo grep ^umask /root/.profile
umask 027
vagrant@archlinux:~$ grep ^umask ~/.profile
umask 027
```

Comment: Have you looked at the default `umask` on vagrant?

Comment: If you set `umask 007` and install vcard the executable will be `-rwxrwx---` (at least in a virtualenv).

Comment: Try `python -c "import os; print os.umask(0)"`

Comment: From my experiments with `umask` and installing vcard, `pip2` just follows the `umask` it gest from the environment

Comment: have you looked at the permissions on pip2 and/or the python executable?

Comment: Do you have `pam_umask` in your PAM configuration (`/etc/pam.conf` or `/etc/pam.d/*`)?

Comment: You should make the "where is my umask set for vagrant" into a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vcard` is not only executable by root, but also by any member of the group root. This is caused by the `umask` being `007` or even more restrictive at the moment `pip2` is started. Just change with `umask 002` or start with:

```
python -c "import os; os.umask(2); os.system('pip2 install vcard')"
```